# loop JSON format

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, loops

I am trying to loop my JSON format but it doesn't work correctly. When I looping the the "id_first" print 1 and 2 correctly but after step toward to the id_second and print undefined despite my loop call only "id_first". How can I achieve that my loop print only id first?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://192.168.1.190/tmp/data.json",
     method: "GET",
     success: function(data) {
       var id_first = [];

       for (var i in data) {
         id_first.push(data[i].id_first);
         alert(data[i].id_first);
       }
     },
     error: function(data) {
       console.log('error');
     }
   });
});
```

Data:

```
 [{
   "id_first": "1",
   "data_first": "1"
 }, {
   "id_first": "2",
   "data_first": "2"
 }, {
   "id_second": "1",
   "data_second": "1"
 }, {
   "id_second": "2",
   "data_second": "2"
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether `id_first` exist with `data[i].id_first != undefined` inside loop
if yes then push into Array. So only valid(not undefined) will be added to `id_first` array

```js
 var id_first=[]
var data =  [{
    "id_first": "1",
    "data_first": "1"   }, {
    "id_first": "2",
    "data_first": "2"  },  {
    "id_second": "1",
    "data_second": "1"  }, {
    "id_second": "2",
    "data_second": "2"  }]
     for(var i in data) {
     if(data[i].id_first != undefined){
          id_first.push(data[i].id_first);
          alert(data[i].id_first);
          }
     }
      console.log(id_first);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether "id_first" property is exists in the JSON object or not, if exists then push it into the array otherwise skip it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.1.190/tmp/data.json", 
        method: "GET", 
        success: function(data) {
          var id_first=[]

          for(var i in data) {

             if(data[i].id_first){
                  id_first.push(data[i].id_first);
                  alert(data[i].id_first);
             }

          }

        },  
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> undefined means that the property you want to access is not available or not defined.

Hence, to overcome from this problem you have to check whether property is exists in the object or not before pushing it into the array.

**DEMO**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.1.190/tmp/data.json", 
        method: "GET", 
        success: function(data) {
          var id_first=[];
          for(var i in data) {
             if(data[i].id_first) {
               id_first.push(data[i].id_first);
             }

          }

        },  
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
```